# foreach concatenate each element to next one

Tags: php

I would like to concatenate each element of array to next one. I want the output array to be:

```
Array
(
[0] => test
[1] => test/test2
[2] => test/test2/test3
[3] => test/test2/test3/test4
)
```

I tried the following way which concatenates each string to itself:

```
$url = preg_split("/[\s\/]+/", "test/test2/test3/test4");
foreach ($url as $dir) {
   $dir .= $dir;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: And you have errors? .. wrong result? .. no result ? .. what's the problem?

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe another way

```
<?php
$data = array( 'test', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4' );
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $data ); $i++ )
{
  if( $i != 0 )
  {
    $new[ $i ] = $new[ $i - 1 ] .'/'. $data[ $i ];
  }
  else
  {
    $new[ $i ] = $data[ $i ];
  }
}
```

var_dump( $new );

Output

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "test"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "test/test2"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "test/test2/test3"
  [3]=>
  string(22) "test/test2/test3/test4"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should obtain the result you need in $my_array

```
$url = explode("/", "test/test2/test3/test4");

$str ='';
foreach($url as $key => $value){
  if ( $str == '') {
     $str .= $str;
  } else {
    $str .= '/'.$str;
  }
  $my_array[$key] = $str ;
  echo $str . '<br />';

}

var_dump($my_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = preg_split("/[\s\/]+/", "test/test2/test3/test4");
$arr = array();
$str = '';
foreach ($url as $key => $dir) {

    if ($key !== 0) {
        $str .= '/' . $dir;
    } else {
        $str .= $dir;
    }

    $arr[] = $str;
}
```

On each iteration concate a string with new value and add it as a separate value for your output array.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way.  For simple splitting just use `explode()`:

```
$url  = explode("/", "test/test2/test3/test4");

foreach($url as $value) {
    $temp[]   = $value;
    $result[] = implode("/", $temp);
}
```

Each time through the loop, add the current value to a temporary array and implode it into the next element of the result.